# What does "assault" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning

This context comes from the movie "The Aviator" by Martin Scorsese.

"I've even managed to coax the luscious Miss De Havilland and her equally luscious sister to accompany me. Though I fear their mother will insist on coming along, to preserve their questionable virtue. We shall **assault** these twin monuments of pristine Britannic beauty nonetheless! What do you say?"

2. To rape.(American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language)

Rape. The victim was sexually assaulted.(Merriam-Webster)

This definition fits but it would be insane if it was the one. The people talking are not serial killers but socialites, uttering it in public while joining their friend at the table, who sits there with his date, who is a famouse actress.

Comment: I think it's a metaphorical usage.  After all, the two women are not literally monuments either.

Comment: They will *challenge* the two sisters, regardless of their chaperone. They want their views and ideas, their conversation.

Comment: @stangdon I tought "monuments" in this context means: *b. An exceptional example: "Thousands of them wrote texts, some of them monuments of dullness" (Robert L. Heilbroner).* And the sentence translates "these twin examples of pristine Britannic beauty". Am I wrong?

Comment: monuments --> *classic examples*.

Comment: It's important to note that even in its literal sense "rape" and "assault" are not synonyms. Rape is equal to "sexual assault" as a phrase.

Comment: Isn't sexual assault simply an attempted rape?

Answer (score 3):

No, much more likely it is [this:](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/assault) c) a concerted effort (as to reach a goal or defeat an adversary).

Here is an example of the word used in the title of a movie: [Assault on Everest](https://www.mntnfilm.com/en/film/assault-on-everest-1977)

Answer (score 0):

It is metaphorical. He is proposing to approach them to engage in conversation.